# Has anyone used UI Testing with react native?

Tags: react-native

Has anyone used UI Testing with react native?  I want to use Snapshot (part of Fastlane) to save my screenshots but when I try to record my clicks in the UI Test I get code that looks like this:

```
app/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.otherElements["    \Ue00e Getting Started \Ue00c   \Ue00e Unlimited Foods \Ue00c   \Ue00e Limited Foods \Ue00c "].otherElements["  \Ue00e Getting Started \Ue00c"]/*[[".otherElements[\"       \\Ue00e   \\Ue004   \\Ue00d   \\Ue006     Info       \\Ue00e Getting Started \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Unlimited Foods \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Limited Foods \\Ue00c  \"]",".otherElements[\"      \\Ue00e   \\Ue004   \\Ue00d   \\Ue006     Info       \\Ue00e Getting Started \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Unlimited Foods \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Limited Foods \\Ue00c  \"]",".otherElements[\"     \\Ue00e   \\Ue004   \\Ue00d   \\Ue006     Info       \\Ue00e Getting Started \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Unlimited Foods \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Limited Foods \\Ue00c \"]",".otherElements[\"    \\Ue00e   \\Ue004   \\Ue00d   \\Ue006     Info       \\Ue00e Getting Started \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Unlimited Foods \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Limited Foods \\Ue00c \"]",".otherElements[\"    Info       \\Ue00e Getting Started \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Unlimited Foods \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Limited Foods \\Ue00c \"]",".otherElements[\"   Info       \\Ue00e Getting Started \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Unlimited Foods \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Limited Foods \\Ue00c \"]",".otherElements[\"     \\Ue00e Getting Started \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Unlimited Foods \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Limited Foods \\Ue00c \"]",".scrollViews.otherElements[\"    \\Ue00e Getting Started \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Unlimited Foods \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Limited Foods \\Ue00c \"]",".otherElements[\"   \\Ue00e Getting Started \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Unlimited Foods \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Limited Foods \\Ue00c\"].otherElements[\"  \\Ue00e Getting Started \\Ue00c\"]",".otherElements[\"  \\Ue00e Getting Started \\Ue00c\"]",".otherElements[\"    \\Ue00e Getting Started \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Unlimited Foods \\Ue00c   \\Ue00e Limited Foods \\Ue00c \"]"],[[[-1,10,8],[-1,7,8],[-1,6,7],[-1,5,6],[-1,4,5],[-1,3,4],[-1,2,3],[-1,1,2],[-1,0,1]],[[-1,10,8],[-1,7,8],[-1,6,7],[-1,5,6],[-1,4,5],[-1,3,4],[-1,2,3],[-1,1,2]],[[-1,10,8],[-1,7,8],[-1,6,7],[-1,5,6],[-1,4,5],[-1,3,4],[-1,2,3]],[[-1,10,8],[-1,7,8],[-1,6,7],[-1,5,6],[-1,4,5],[-1,3,4]],[[-1,10,8],[-1,7,8],[-1,6,7],[-1,5,6],[-1,4,5]],[[-1,10,8],[-1,7,8],[-1,6,7],[-1,5,6]],[[-1,10,8],[-1,7,8],[-1,6,7]],[[-1,10,8],[-1,7,8]],[[-1,9],[-1,8]]],[0,0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/.tap()
```

and it won't run, it gives errors like:

```
Invalid escape sequence in literal
```

Comment: I haven't used UI Testing but I did find this article really helpful for integration testing with React Native using Appium: http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2015/11/08/react-native-integration-tests/